# How to forward ssh X11 from an ssh session to base computer?

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I am working from out of town, so I need to connect my computer at campus. Normally, when I am around the campus I can just use my ip of lab computer to forward x11 like;

```
ssh -X acc@lab-computer ~/idea-IC/bin/idea.sh
```

However,since I am out of town, I can only connect a computer of my lab then ssh to my computer but I couldn't forward X11 from my lab-computer to my laptop through a computer at my lab.

Any idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it. I don't know why I didn't think of it before.

First;

```
ssh -X account@lab-a-computer
```

then;

```
ssh -X my-account@my-lab-computer ~/idea-IC/bin/idea.sh
```

brings the gui to my laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used X2go: http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php

And the X2go client on my computer....  The wiki I linked should get you started and there is plenty on the web about setting up for particular distros since you did not mention one in your question.  Note I belevie you will need `root` privileges to install.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop and 14.04 on my lab computer. Can I install this from ssh?

Comment: Simple google search gave me: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-x2goserver-on-ubuntu-14.04-as-vnc-alternative  ... And Yes I install on my remote servers a few times... even thought it says 14.04 it should work on 15.10